# Kafka Streams Windowed Key to Human Readable

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I am doing window aggregation on a kafka stream.
It works fine and does correct aggregation.
here's the code in scala.
`CallRecord` is a case class.

```
    builder
  .stream[String, String](input_topic)
  .mapValues((elm) => {
    parse(elm).extract[CallRecord]
  })
  .groupBy((key, value) => {
    value.agentId
  })
  .windowedBy(every15Minute)
  .aggregate(CallRecordAggByAgent.empty)((_, callRecord, aggregator) => {
    CallRecordAggByAgent(
      callRecord.agentId,
      ((callRecord.durationMinutes + aggregator.durationMinutesAvg) / aggregator.count).roundD,
      ((callRecord.waitingMinutes + aggregator.waitingMinutesAvg) / aggregator.count).roundD,
      ((callRecord.customerScore + aggregator.scoreAvg) / aggregator.count).roundD,
      aggregator.count + 1
    )
  })
  .mapValues((elm) => {
    write(elm)
  })
  .toStream
  .to(output_topic)
```

In output topic I see key something like this.
[image: output_topic key]

When I try to read this from KSQLDB when I create a stream on this topic I see values for rowkey like this `3w�H�@`
I understand this is deserialization issue, but I would like to either be able to deserialize this directly in KSQL or make it as Long of millis while streaming to output_topic.
My understanding is this should be easily achieved but I think I miss some nuance here.

Comment: were you able to solve?

Comment: @dune98 Sorry forgot to post my answer. Now it's there, please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I gave is the following. Apparently it was not very hard.

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.Serialization.write

builder
      .stream[String, String](args.INPUT_TOPIC)
      .mapValues((elm) => {
        parse(elm).extract[CallRecord]
      })
      .groupBy((key, value) => {
        value.agentId
      })
      .windowedBy(every15Minute)
      .aggregate(CallRecordAggByAgent.empty)((_, callRecord, aggregator) => {
        CallRecordAggByAgent(
          callRecord.agentId,
          ((callRecord.durationMinutes + aggregator.durationMinutesAvg) / aggregator.count).roundD,
          ((callRecord.waitingMinutes + aggregator.waitingMinutesAvg) / aggregator.count).roundD,
          ((callRecord.customerScore + aggregator.scoreAvg) / aggregator.count).roundD,
          aggregator.count + 1
        )
      })
      .mapValues((elm) => {
        write(elm)
      })
      .toStream
      .selectKey((k, v) => {
        s"${k.key()}@${k.window().startTime().toEpochMilli.toString}"
      })
      .to(args.OUTPUT_TOPIC)
```

`selectKey` provides this possibility to change the key for grouping,
so before streaming to output topic I extract the timestamp from the key and make it as a string.